# Trying to capture stdout of background process in bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins

I wrote the following to be used with Jenkins to kick off my selenium tests. Now since they are being executed as background processes, when they fail Jenkins believes they haven't. As you can see my futile attempt on making this work. Any ideas? Thought about piping the output into a file and grepping for keywords. Then I realized I don't know how to reflect an error if a grep for string returns true.

```
#!/bin/bash

FAIL=0


echo "starting"


ruby /root/selenium-tests/test/test1.rb &   
ruby /root/selenium-tests/test/test2.rb & 
ruby /root/selenium-tests/test/test3.rb & 

#wait

for job in `jobs -p`
do
    echo $job
    wait $job || let "FAIL+=1"
done

echo $FAIL

if [ "$FAIL" == "0" ];
then

   echo  "PASS"

else

    echo "FAIL! ($FAIL)"

fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins most likely looks at the process exit code to determine whether tests fails. This is what all Unix tools do.

There are multiple ways of doing this. If your test files output something like "FAIL" instead of properly returning an exit code, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  ruby /root/selenium-tests/test/test1.rb &   
  ruby /root/selenium-tests/test/test2.rb & 
  ruby /root/selenium-tests/test/test3.rb & 
  wait
) > log

! grep "FAIL" log
exit $?  # <- happens implicitly at the end of the script, and can be left out
```

In this case, `grep` finding "FAIL" will cause the script to fail, and Jenkins to detect the failure.

The more correct way, if your scripts return proper exit codes, is your method but without relying on job control (which by default is turned off in non-interactive shells), and returning correct exit codes:

```
for test in /root/selenium-tests/test/test*.rb
do
    ruby "$test" &
    pids+=( $! )
done

for pid in "${pids[@]}"
do
    if wait $pid
    then
        echo "$pid succeeded"
    else
        echo "$pid failed"
        (( failures++ ))
    fi
done

if [[ $failures -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "FAIL: $failures failed tests"
    exit 1  # return failure
else
    echo "PASS!"
    exit 0  # return success
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! That resolved my issue, and learned quite a bit in the process.